# Wrapped titles of longtable columns

Tags: titles, longtable, multicolumn, wrap

I suspect there's something I've added to my code which I didn't understand and don't want.  The text of the title of my longtable's columns doesn't seem to want to wrap.  Could someone tell me where I've gone wrong please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

% General packages to use
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Table-related stuff
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} % for ExtraRowHeight

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}

\setlength{\LTpre}{6pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{6pt}

\begin{document}

 \rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{}
\large
\begin{longtable}{Cp{2.5cm}Cp{2.5cm}Cp{3cm}Cp{2.5cm}}
\hline

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Long heading which I want to wrap}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Short heading}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Short heading}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Short heading}} \\ \hline
\endhead
Nisanu & Nisan & Mar./Apr. & Apr. \\
Aiaru & Iyyar & Apr./May & May \\
Simanu & Sivan & May/June & June \\
Duzu & Tammuz & June/July & July \\
Abu & Ab & July/Aug. & Aug. \\
Ululu & Elul & Aug./Sep. & Sep. \\
Tashritu & Tishri & Sep./Oct. & Oct. \\
Arahsamnu & Heshvan & Oct./Nov. & Nov. \\
Kislimu & Kislev & Nov./Dec. & Dec. \\
Tebetu & Tebeth & Dec./Jan. & Jan. \\
Shabatu & Shebat & Jan./Feb. & Feb. \\
Addaru & Adar & Feb./Mar. & Mar. \\

\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Many thanks,

James.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use

```
\textbf{Long heading which I want to wrap}
```

instead of

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Long heading which I want to wrap}}
```

otherwise it results in a non-fixed column, where the text can't wrap.

No need for others `\multicolumn`s, either. Also `2.5cm` is not enough, changed to `3cm` in every column.

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

% General packages to use
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Table-related stuff
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} % for ExtraRowHeight

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm}

\setlength{\LTpre}{6pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{6pt}

\begin{document}

 \rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{}
\large
\begin{longtable}{Cp{3cm}Cp{3cm}Cp{3cm}Cp{3cm}}
\hline

\textbf{Long heading which I want to wrap}
& \textbf{Short heading}
& \textbf{Short heading}
& \textbf{Short heading} \\ \hline
\endhead
Nisanu & Nisan & Mar./Apr. & Apr. \\
Aiaru & Iyyar & Apr./May & May \\
Simanu & Sivan & May/June & June \\
Duzu & Tammuz & June/July & July \\
Abu & Ab & July/Aug. & Aug. \\
Ululu & Elul & Aug./Sep. & Sep. \\
Tashritu & Tishri & Sep./Oct. & Oct. \\
Arahsamnu & Heshvan & Oct./Nov. & Nov. \\
Kislimu & Kislev & Nov./Dec. & Dec. \\
Tebetu & Tebeth & Dec./Jan. & Jan. \\
Shabatu & Shebat & Jan./Feb. & Feb. \\
Addaru & Adar & Feb./Mar. & Mar. \\

\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want bottom aligment use `Cb{3cm}` instead of `Cp{3cm}`

Answer (score 3):

Your table setup is a bit complicated. Rather than define a multitude of separate column types which actually just act on the `p` column type, it may be more straightforward to load the `ragged2e` package and set up the following definition:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

(The point of using `\Centering` instead of `\centering` is that the former macro allows hyphenation.) I've used `C{3cm}` for columns 2 thru 4 in the example below. I suspect, though, that it would be OK to simply use `c` for these columns. Note also that I've gotten rid of all `\mulicolumn` "wrappers".

By the way, since you have the statement `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, no need to state `\usepackage{colortbl}` as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

% General packages to use
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Table-related stuff
%\usepackage{colortbl} % no need to load it separately
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} % for ExtraRowHeight
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \Centering macro
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.2cm} % default value: 6pt

\setlength{\LTpre}{6pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{6pt}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{}
{\large
\begin{longtable}{C{4.25cm} C{3cm} C{3cm} C{3cm} }
\hline
\textbf{Long heading which I want to wrap} 
& \textbf{Short heading} & \textbf{Short heading} & \textbf{Short heading} \\ 
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
Nisanu & Nisan & Mar./Apr. & Apr. \\
Aiaru & Iyyar & Apr./May & May \\
Simanu & Sivan & May/June & June \\
Duzu & Tammuz & June/July & July \\
Abu & Ab & July/Aug. & Aug. \\
Ululu & Elul & Aug./Sep. & Sep. \\
Tashritu & Tishri & Sep./Oct. & Oct. \\
Arahsamnu & Heshvan & Oct./Nov. & Nov. \\
Kislimu & Kislev & Nov./Dec. & Dec. \\
Tebetu & Tebeth & Dec./Jan. & Jan. \\
Shabatu & Shebat & Jan./Feb. & Feb. \\
Addaru & Adar & Feb./Mar. & Mar. \\
\end{longtable}
} % end of scope of \large directive
\end{document}
```

---

Just for comparison, here's the look that results if `C{2.5cm}` is used for all four columns -- note that the text in all four column headers wraps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have use `\multicolumn` to replace the `p` (parbox) specification for that cell by `c` which is a single line cell (like `\mbox`).

You do not want to get rid of the parbox so don't use `\multicolumn` just use `\centering`

In the last column you will need `\centering\arraybackslash` as otherwise the following `\\` will just make a centred linebreak within the cell not end the table row as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with plain `c` column types, thanks to the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks and a common formatting of column heads. I also replaced the use of `\arraystretch=1.5` with loading the `cellspace` package, so as to ensure a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns prefixed with the letter `S`.

If you want column headings borrom aligned rather than the default vertically and horizontally centred, you can do it with the `\theadalign` parameter, which must containt a pair of values from {t,c,b} and {l,r,c}:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

% General packages to use
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

% Table-related stuff
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} %
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}

\setlength{\LTpre}{6pt}
\setlength{\LTpost}{6pt}

\begin{document}

 \rowcolors{1}{lightgray}{}
\large
\begin{longtable}{Scccc}
\hline
\thead{Long heading which\\ I want to wrap}
& \thead{Short heading}
& \thead{Short heading}
& \thead{Short heading} \\
\hline
\endhead
Nisanu & Nisan & Mar./Apr. & Apr. \\
Aiaru & Iyyar & Apr./May & May \\
Simanu & Sivan & May/June & June \\
Duzu & Tammuz & June/July & July \\
Abu & Ab & July/Aug. & Aug. \\
Ululu & Elul & Aug./Sep. & Sep. \\
Tashritu & Tishri & Sep./Oct. & Oct. \\
Arahsamnu & Heshvan & Oct./Nov. & Nov. \\
Kislimu & Kislev & Nov./Dec. & Dec. \\
Tebetu & Tebeth & Dec./Jan. & Jan. \\
Shabatu & Shebat & Jan./Feb. & Feb. \\
Addaru & Adar & Feb./Mar. & Mar. \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard.  That makes things very controllable in terms of how the wrapping works, so will come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for making the changes.  That now centres the headings perfectly.